# How do I combine results from both JSON and XML files in a unified output in ASP.NET web service

Tags: c#, json, xml

I am having an XML file which contains details Library and books and a JSON file which also contains details Library and books as well, but with a different structure and we need a web service which manipulates the two different files and returns a unified output as XML to a front-end MVC app that displays returned results in a grid (each row represent a hotel with child rows that represent rooms) with a filtration facility. Combine results from both JSON and XML files in a unified output as XML.

Comment: What you need is a class which represents the entity. Then you need to deserialize the data from xml and json file to create lists of the entities. Merge the list by using List.AddRange method and bind final list to the datagrid. For filter and sort feature you need to store the final list to some storage so that you can apply filtering and sorting on that without processing the files again.

Comment: You have stated what you need, that is fine. But what is your problem? Where is your code, where does your code fail? Please read the [FAQ] and [ask].